# Read cgroups data without mounting it

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, resources, docker, cgroups

I have some cgroups-managed services (actually running in docker). To fairly schedule some resource-demanding tasks, containerized services need to know it exact (as far as possible) resource usage. I've decided to read this metrics from cgroups.

But there is a problem. I known two ways to access cgroup data from docker container.

1. Mount cgroups directly from the inside of container. To accomplish that, I need to give CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability to container. I think this is too hard-boiled way to only read resource usage metrics.
2. Use docker volume, pointing to host cgroups mountpoint. This solution more or less appropriate, but I'am lookin' more elegant way.

I am not an "kernel-guy" and not familiar with kernel sources and documentation, so I am able to ask noob's question.

Is there any kernel interface which allows me to read cgroups metrics without mounting cgroups filesystem?

Comment: The only interface you get in the user space is by mounting  cgroups or from the `/proc/<pid>/cgourp/`, (but only limited to the cgroups a process belongs to). If you are looking for a syscall for reading cgroups data, its not available IMU. Docker requires cgroups services (cgconfig, cgred, etc)to be running, therefore its would require you to mount the cgroups.

Comment: I've asked this question in docker mailing list. They point me to  https://groups.google.com/d/msg/docker-user/0l6qyYTKXnI/UREl7tFDgr0J This is exactly my second option in the question. I think, your comment is quite comprehesive, so I'd like to accept it as answer.

Comment: I will add this under the answers section instead of this being a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only interface you get in the user space is by mounting cgroups or from the `/proc/<pid>/cgourps`, (but only limited to the cgroups a process belongs to). If you are looking for a syscall() for reading cgroups data, its not available IMU. Docker requires cgroups services (cgconfig, cgred, etc)to be running, therefore its would require you to mount the cgroups.